# Elasticsearch aggregation count mismatch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting improper aggregation count from ES query. I understand from ES documentation cardinality and term aggregations are not accurate but which i got is having too much difference.

Mapping of my index is

```
    {
        "dynamic_templates": [{
            "template_action": {
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "*"
            }
        }],
        "_parent": {
            "type": "users"
        },
        "date_detection": False,
        "properties": {
            "traits": {
                "type": "object"
            },
            "cl_utm_params": {
                "type": "object"
            },
            "cl_other_params": {
                "type": "object"
            },
            "cl_triggered_ts": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
```

a sample document

```
   {
      "client_id": "cl58vivh8w7t",
      "user_id": "CL.1122029143.1904488380.1218174474.2049762488",
      "session_id": "CL.1886305621.906039613",
      "source": "Google",
      "action": "pageview",
      "cl_triggered_ts": "2016-09-09T00:13:33.818Z",
      "browser": "Microsoft Edge 13",
      "platform": "Windows 10",
      "screen_size": "1920 x 1080",
      "device": "Desktop",
      "ip_address": "98.236.246.165",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Weirton",
      "postal_code": "26062",
      "location": "40.4224, -80.5739",
      "timezone": "America/New_York",
      "state": "West Virginia",
      "continent": "North America",
      "isp": "Comcast Cable",
      "browser_language": "",
      "traits": {},
      "cl_utm_params": {},
      "cl_other_params": {}
    }
```

from below query i am getting unique no of sessions for each source and unique no of sessions for each device by source using bucket and metric aggregations

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"match": {"client_id": "cl58vivh8w7t"}}
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_source": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "source"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "total_unique_sessions": {"cardinality": {"field": "session_id"}},
            "per_device": {
                "terms": {"field": "device"},
                "aggs": {"device_session": {"cardinality": {"field": "session_id"}}}
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

for reference i have given a single bucket below. from this the sum of each device's session value should be equal to the total_unique_sessions value.

I suspect is there something wrong with my query or my calculations?

```
{
      "key": "www.google.com",
      "doc_count": 68947,
      "per_device": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Desktop",
            "doc_count": 49254,
            "device_session": {
              "value": 2413
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Mobile",
            "doc_count": 16317,
            "device_session": {
              "value": 3222
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Tablet",
            "doc_count": 3343,
            "device_session": {
              "value": 636
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "TV",
            "doc_count": 33,
            "device_session": {
              "value": 9
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "total_unique_sessions": {
        "value": 9058
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have are using match query.

Normally we do term query for aggregation. I think match is causing this problem.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"term": {"client_id": "cl58vivh8w7t"}}
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_source": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "source"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "total_unique_sessions": {"cardinality": {"field": "session_id"}},
            "per_device": {
                "terms": {"field": "device"},
                "aggs": {"device_session": {"cardinality": {"field": "session_id"}}}
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: yeah, it is good to use term over match on analysed fields for quicker results but here it doesn't make sense on this query as client_id is not_analysed. both results same numbers.